# How to Specify URI to a local File in PyGtk LinkButton

Tags: python, pygtk

I need to create a link button (gtk.LinkButton) with an URI to a local file. Does anyone know what is a valid URI format for a local file ? I want to specify a relative folder example: ../some_folder/file_i_need_to_open.txt

If this is can't be done, I don't mind putting the file in the same folder as the python source code =)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like: `file:///usr/bin/` is generally used for local URI. But maybe just `/usr/bin/` works too. Have you tried it?

Comment: that works! But what if I have a relative path ? let just say file:///../some_folder/file_i_need_to_open.txt

Comment: Have you tried that then? If it doesn't work, you can always use `os.path.abspath`.